# js file structure, return values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Background story: I'm getting into js file structure and building a helper where I get a handlebars template and populating it (to be used in the handlebars driven styleguide tool, fabricator).

My `returnTemplate()` function returns undefined, and I can't figure out why? 
it does get to into `renderTemplate()` and does its thing, but the return value fails to travel all the way back to the button click.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qagd6e5L/1/)

```
var Button = (function() {
  function init() {
    $('.js-template-trigger').on('click', function() {
      var context = {
        name: 'John Wick'
      }

      var value = TemplateHelper.returnTemplate('demo-template', context);
      console.log('value:', value);
    });
  }

  return {
    init: init
  };
})();

$(function() {
  Button.init();
});


var TemplateHelper = (function() {
  function getTemplate(templateId, callBack, context) {
    //$.get('/data/templates.html#' + templateId).done(callBack);
    console.log('what is:', $('#demo-template')[0].outerHTML);

    callBack($('#demo-template')[0].outerHTML);
  }

  function renderTemplate(source, context) {
    console.log('renderTemplate');

    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
    var html = template(context);

    console.log('renderTemplate html:', html);
    console.log('renderTemplate html inner:', $(html).html());

    return $(html).html();
  }

  function returnTemplate(templateId, context) {
    var callBack = function(data) {
      renderTemplate(data, context);
    }

    return getTemplate(templateId, callBack, context);
  }

  function appendToTemplate(templateId, context, targetAppend) {
    var callBack = function(data) {
      if (data !== undefined) {
        var html = renderTemplate(source, context);
        $(html).appendTo($(targetAppend));
      }
    }

    getTemplate(templateId, callBack, context);
  }

  return {
    returnTemplate: returnTemplate
  };
})();
```

html

```
<button type="button" class="js-template-trigger">click me</button>

    <script id="demo-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
      <div style="height: 50px; width: 100%; background-color: deepskyblue;">{{name}}</div>
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `returnTemplate` will return something if your function `getTemplate` returns something. So you can add `return` before the instruction `callBack($('#demo-template')[0].outerHTML);`. In the same way, your callback function must return something : add `return` before the instruction `renderTemplate(data, context);` (in the definition of your var callback).

Comment: Awesome. I tried that but missed to add in the callback definition. Thanks.

Comment: One thing though, if I return the `$.get();` as intended I don't just get the value, but the whole get function, how do I extract a value?

Comment: `$.get()` is asynchronous, so you can't get immediatly the value (and his return value is the function, as you discovered). I think you'll have to look at Promise, that can do what you want : just go here https://davidwalsh.name/promises